# Опечатка во всплывающей подсказке бронзовых знаков

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Заметил опечатку во всплывающей подсказке, появляющейся при наведении мышки на любой бронзовый знак.

Вместо "бронзовый" знак написано "брон**о**зовый".

P.S. И что же мне ещё написать, чтобы сообщение прошло?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это была ошибка перевода, спасибо, что сообщили!

Исправил в Транзифексе, правильная строка выкатится, как обычно, со следующим обновлением.